# Displaying and navigating through the user's home directory in a Flask app

Tags: python, linux, logging, filesystems

I'm working on a project where I need to create a web application that authenticates users based on the /etc/shadow system file. I also need to track user actions, such as login, logout, and file downloads, in a log file. Finally, I need to deploy the application as a Linux service.

Once a user logs in, they should see their home directory displayed in a table, which they can use to navigate through directories. If a file is a text file, the application should display its content. Additionally, the "Files" section should show the number of files owned by the logged-in user, "Dirs" should show the number of directories owned by the logged-in user, and "Space" should contain the total amount of space occupied by the logged-in user.

However, I'm having trouble implementing the feature that displays the user's home directory and allows them to navigate through directories. I've tried using the os and glob modules in Python, but I'm not sure how to make it recursive.

this is the final version that i need to get
[image]

this is my version so far :

[image]

I've tried using the os and glob modules in Python, but I'm not sure how to make it recursive.

Do you have any suggestions or advice on how to proceed? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

also this is what i did so far
this is my dal.py file

```
import crypt

import spwd
import subprocess
import os
from prettytable import PrettyTable


class UserDao:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def user_exists(self, username):
        try:
            # Get the shadow entry for the user
            shadow_entry = spwd.getspnam(username)
            return True
        except KeyError:
            # User does not exist
            return False

    def verify_password(self, user, password):
    # Use sudo to read the shadow file with root privileges
        cmd = ['sudo', '-S', 'cat', '/etc/shadow']
        try:
            proc = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, input=password.encode(), check=True)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            # The password was incorrect or the user doesn't have permission to read the shadow file
            return False

        # Parse the output of the `sudo cat /etc/shadow` command to get the hashed password for the given user
        for line in proc.stdout.decode().split('\n'):
            fields = line.strip().split(':')
            if fields[0] == user:
                hashed_password = fields[1]
                break
        else:
            raise ValueError("User not found in shadow file")

        # Verify the password against the hashed password
        return crypt.crypt(password, hashed_password) == hashed_password
 
    

    def files_count(self, user):
        cmd = f"find /home/{user} -type f  | wc -l"
        # to handle the sudo 
        result = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
        output = result.stdout.strip().split('\n')
        if output[-1]:
            file_count = int(output[-1])
        else:
            file_count = 0

        return file_count
    
    
    
    def count_directories(self, username):
        """
        Returns the number of directories for the given user.
        """
        user_dir = os.path.join('/home', username)
        if not os.path.isdir(user_dir):
            return 0
        return sum([1 for f in os.listdir(user_dir) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(user_dir, f))])



    def get_user_space(self, username):
        user_dir = f'/home/{username}'
        result = subprocess.run(['du', '-sh', user_dir], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        space_used = result.stdout.decode('utf-8').split('\t')[0]
        space_used_num = space_used[:-1]  # remove the last character (unit)
        return space_used_num


  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Prompt the user for their username and password
    user = input('Enter your username: ')
    password = input('Enter your password: ')

    # Create a UserDao object and use it to verify the password and count the files
    user_dao = UserDao()
    if user_dao.verify_password(user, password):
        print('Password verified')
        file_count = user_dao.files_count(user)
        dirs_count = user_dao.count_directories(user)
        space_used = user_dao.get_user_space(user)
        
        print(f"Number of files: {file_count}")
        print(f"Number of direcs: {dirs_count }")
        print(f"Space used:{space_used}")
        
    else:
        print('Authentification Failure')
```

this is my controller.py

```
from dal import UserDao
from datetime import datetime
import logging
import hashlib
from flask import (
    Flask,
    request,
    render_template,
    redirect,
    session,
    url_for,
    send_file,
    jsonify
)
import shutil

# logging.basicConfig(filename="log.txt")

app = Flask(__name__)

# Set the secret key for the session
app.secret_key = b'_5#y2L"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'

# Create an instance of the UserDao
user_dao = UserDao()



@app.route('/')
def home():
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
   



@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():

    error = ""

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

        # Verify the password
        if user_dao.verify_password(username, password):
            # Store the username in the session
            session['username'] = username

            # Log the login action
            with open('app.log', 'a') as f:
                f.write(f"{datetime.now()} - {username} logged in\n")
            return render_template('app.html')

        else:
            error = 'Invalid username or password'

    return render_template('login.html', error=error)

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    # retrieve the username from the session
    username = session.get('username')
    if username:
        # remove the user's session information
        session.pop('username', None)
        # Log the logout action
        with open('app.log', 'a') as f:
             f.write(f"{datetime.now()} - {username} logged out\n")
    # redirect the user to the login page
    return redirect(url_for('login'))



@app.route('/files')
def files():
    # retrieve the username from the session
    username = session.get('username')
    if username:
        # Call the files_count method of UserDao to get the file count, total size, and
        files_count = user_dao.files_count(username)
        return render_template('app.html', file_count=files_count)
    else:
         return jsonify({'error': 'User not authenticated'}), 401


@app.route('/dirs')
def directories():
    # retrieve the username from the session
    username = session.get('username')
    if username:
        # Call the count_directories method of UserDao to get the directories count
        directories_count = user_dao.count_directories(username)
        return render_template('app.html', directories_count=directories_count)
    else:
        return jsonify({'error': 'User not authenticated'}), 401
    

@app.route('/space')
def space():
    # retrieve the username from the session
    username = session.get('username')
    if username:
        # Call the get_user_space method of UserDao to get the space used by the user
        used_space = user_dao.get_user_space(username)
        print(used_space) # print used_space to see its value
        space_used_int = float(used_space.split()[0]) # convert space used string to float
        space_used_str = f"{space_used_int:.1f} GB" # add "GB" to the end of the space used string
        return render_template('app.html', space_used=space_used_str)
    else:
        return jsonify({'error': 'User not authenticated'}), 401

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```